# Terraform forget resource and recreate?

Tags: terraform

I am new to terraform and have been playing with it for a while. In the scenario I am trying to execute, I am trying to create a stack for each deployment of mine. I am able to create the resources I need. However, when I want to deploy a new stack, it is trying to destroy the already existing stack. I have tried to use the lifecycle key with prevent destroy, but that throws an error saying the resource cannot be deleted.

```
the plan would destroy this resource, but it currently has lifecycle.prevent_destroy set to true. To avoid this error and continue with the plan, either disable lifecycle.prevent_destroy or adjust the scope of the plan using the -target flag.
```

Is there no way to skip or make terraform "forget" the resource it created? I understand this is tricky because of the state file that terraform maintains, but any leads would help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put up your Terraform.

Comment: You should be using separate state files and/or workspaces if you want to keep multiple deployed Terraform stacks.

Comment: for different deployments which are independent check workspaces (https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html). About the destroying: what kind of resource do you want to destroy and reuse?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove resources from the state using `terraform state rm <resource>`, maybe that's what you are looking for?

More information available at https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/rm.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use terraform workspaces for different deployments (environments ?). So you will be able to create different resources for different envs (this is mentioned in this comment [Terraform forget resource and recreate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325811/terraform-forget-resource-and-recreate?rq=1#comment87669475_50325811))

Information: https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html